# "на глазу" или "на глазе" и "в глазу" или "в глазе"

Tags: падежи

Вроде встречается и то и то. Как все таки правильно?

> Даль и дом, и тягучий раздвоенный свет в его глазе.
>
> К тому же в загадочном глазе тёти Мари ...   Во всевидящем
> циклопическом красном глазе HAL'a можно ...
>
> В глазу человека есть два вида...
>
> Ты слишком горячий, ты на одном глазе не остановишься. (Ф. Искандер)
>
> с бельмом на правом глазе (Горький)
>
> слезинка застыла на левом глазе (Виноградов. Повесть о трех братьях)